# order() function in R sorts integers "alphabetically"

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I start with a vector which I cbind() to a list of characters and then convert to a data frame as such:

```
numbers <- c(110, 5, 43, 1008)
mat <- cbind(letters, numbers)
letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df <- data.frame(mat)
```

I applied the sorting:

```
df[order(df[,2]),]
```

and I get:

```
  letters numbers
4       D    1008
1       A     110
3       C      43
2       B       5
```

It's sorting the column as if it looks at the first number, then the second etc. and I CANNOT figure it out. The sort() function works on the column, but I can't seem to apply to all rows...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created your data.frame the wrong way.  By starting from a character matrix, **everything** remains a character matrix.  You need an `as.numeric()` in there (or start differently).

```
R> df <- data.frame(letters=LETTERS[1:4], numbers=c(110, 5, 43, 1008),
+                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
R> df
  letters numbers
1       A     110
2       B       5
3       C      43
4       D    1008
R>
```

We can check the column types:

```
R> sapply(df, class)
    letters     numbers 
"character"   "numeric" 
R>
```

And with that, sorting works as expected:

```
R> df[order(df[,2]),]
  letters numbers
2       B       5
3       C      43
1       A     110
4       D    1008
R>
```

Comment: Could you show me how you would use the as.numeric()? I've actually tried that, but when I do that after creating my data frame it actually just associates a number to the "numbers" column according to the order.

Comment: When you have `df` as you had it:  `df[,2] <- as.numeric(df[,2])`  You can of course index by column name too.